# tensorflow android with react-native can't work normally

Tags: android, react-native, tensorflow, bazel

I put react-native.jar to tensorflow android's directory and add configuration to `tensorflow/examples/android/BUILD` file like this:

```
java_import(
    name = "react-native",
    jars = [
        "react-native-0.39.2-sources.jar",
    ],
)
```

Now run `bazel build //tensorflow/examples/android:tensorflow_demo` work well. But then use `import com.facebook.react.*;` in java file and run `bazel build ...` again, it throws a nonexistent error, can't find `com.facebook.react.*` package.

Answer (score 1):

In order to expose the classes in the JAR to the Java code in the Android build, you need to add a dependency in the android_binary that you are building on the java_import you have created.

For example:

```
    # tensorflow/examples/android/BUILD

    java_import(
        name = "react-native",
        jars = [
            "react-native-0.39.2-sources.jar",
        ],
    )

    android_binary(
        name = "tensorflow_demo",
        srcs = glob(["src/**/*.java"]),
        deps = [
            ":tensorflow_native_libs",
            "//tensorflow/contrib/android:android_tensorflow_inference_java",
            ":react-native",
        ],
    )
```